# why isn't the fadeIn option working?

Tags: jquery, html

```
</header>
<section id="video">
<video autoplay loop class="video">

<source src="ink.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</section>
<section id="meat">
<P>
<span class="first">  XXXXXX</span>
<br/>
<span class="second">  xxxxx </span>
</P>
</section>
<footer id="end_page">
</footer>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#meat"). fadeIn("slow");
});
```

//I want the content to fadein slowly after the page loads. why isn't the fadeIn option working? also how to display nav bar when we mouseover the content of the body?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to hide before showing the item.  Since it was already visible, jQuery did nothing.  As for your second question, we can add a `hover` event:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#meat").hide();
  $("#meat").fadeIn(3000);
  $("#meat").hover(function (){
    $("#navbar").stop(true,true).fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  position:fixed;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</header>

<div id="navbar"><a href="#">test</a></div>
<section id="video">
<video autoplay loop class="video">

<source src="ink.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</section>
<section id="meat">
<P>
<span class="first">  XXXXXX</span>
<br/>
<span class="second">  xxxxx </span>
</P>
</section>
<footer id="end_page">
</footer>
```